# Is there any function in selenium to input text in field which is not visible using java?

Tags: selenium, automation, frame, sendkeys

[Enter text in ABSTRACT TILE filed using send keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKPJV.jpg)I'm trying to input text in ABSTRACT_TITLE using send-keys in selenium.
I tried switching frames and giving input.

```
<div id="reTitleCenter" class="reContent" style="height: 2.91667em;" xpath="1">
    <label for="reTitleContentHiddenTextarea" style="display:none;">RadEditor hidden textarea</label>
    <textarea id="reTitleContentHiddenTextarea" name="ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$phDesktop$cphContent$cphContent$reTitle" rows="4" cols="20" style="display:none;"></textarea>
    <iframe frameborder="0" src="javascript:'<html></html>';" id="reTitle_contentIframe" title="Rich text editor with ID reTitle" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">Your browser does not support inline frames or is currently configured not to display inline frames.</iframe>
    <textarea class="reTextArea reTextAreaHidden"></textarea>
</div>
```

the code samples I tried -

```
driver.switchTo().frame("reTitle");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='reTitleTop']/div[@class='RadEditor_Bootstrap reToolBarWrapper']")).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='reTitleTop']/div[@class='RadEditor_Bootstrap reToolBarWrapper']")).sendKeys("This is demo abstract");
```

***OR***

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); 
WebElement Abstract_title = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html//body")); 
Abstract_title.sendKeys("This is abstract demo selenium");
```

***OR***

```
selenium.SelectFrame("xpath_of_iframe"); (Don't know how to use it) 
selenium.Type("//html/body","Thank you");
```

Comment: please provide code you tried..

Comment: driver.switchTo().frame("reTitle");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='reTitleTop']/div[@class='RadEditor_Bootstrap reToolBarWrapper']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='reTitleTop']/div[@class='RadEditor_Bootstrap reToolBarWrapper']")).sendKeys("This is demo abstract");
OR
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
WebElement Abstract_title = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html//body"));
Abstract_title.sendKeys("This is abstract demo selenium");
OR
selenium.SelectFrame("xpath_of_iframe"); (Don't know how to use it)
selenium.Type("//html/body","Thank you");

Comment: Selenium is designed to interact with the page as a user would so it will not allow you to send keys to an invisible element. Why would you want to do that anyway?

Comment: I'm automating the test case and It's mandatory filed. So, I need to give some input to processed further.